# How to push notification from parse.com to mobile app without integrate parse SDK?

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I want to built a rest service by using parse.com. My mobile app will interact with parse via rest api by send http request. Without integrating parse SDK into my app, how can i setup push notification from parse to my app?Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can not do that, because for handle the push notification in your app, you need parse SDK for PFPUSH object.